# Youtube Data Api V3 - suddenly "queries per day" has been resetted to 0 from 300 000

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have been using youtube data api v3 for 3 years. we aware of fact that youtube gives us provision to crawl data using client id, client secret and one security key as authenticated user.

Once in month i get exhausted with token usages but on next day it get reset at 12.30pm IST. but now I am seeing usages haven't been reset for 2 days. i checked on dashboard in quota section where i found

- Query per min per user 180 000
- Query per 100 min per user 300 000
- Query per day 0 (Unable to reset manually.)

How to get that resolved? i found only support system for this is stackoverflow.

FYI : i do regenerate security and tried accessing but i can not.

Comment: if you have been downgraded to 0 quota per day.  I would suspect that you are going to have to apply for a quota extension.

Comment: thank DalmTo. i requested for quota form recently and they will update us.